# Strange Values in SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS table RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, locking

I’ve been trying to understand some strange values in the RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID column of SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS when RESOURCE_TYPE is “OBJECT”. Although these should be object Ids, I cannot determine what object they actually refer to.

I’ve tried everything I can think of, including querying all system tables with columns of type INT and BIGINT to see if I can find the value. No luck. The funny values actually appear in SYS.DM_TRAN_LOCKS, SYS.SYSLOCKINFO and SP_LOCK.

(Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit), version 9.00.4053.00 (SP3 + a security patch))

Comment: What does (select) object_name(RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID) return?

Comment: It returns NULL. I tried passing in the content of the RESOURCE_DATABASE_ID column as a second param to OBJECT_NAME,but it it made no difference. 

The following query returns some values for OBJECT_NAME, but not others, as the IDs don’t seem to refer to schema-scoped objects, so they don’t exist in sys.all_objects. They might refer to non-schema-scoped objects but there’s very little information on how to find all non-schema-scoped objects.

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(resource_associated_entity_id, resource_database_id) AS object_name, * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_type = 'OBJECT'

Answer (score 2):

```
select db_name(resource_database_id),object_name(resource_associated_entity_id),* from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_session_id is not null
and resource_associated_entity_id <> 0

select db_name(resource_database_id),object_name(resource_associated_entity_id),* from sys.dm_tran_locks
where request_session_id is not null
and db_name(resource_database_id)='SamsungeStore'
and resource_associated_entity_id <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It can return Object ID, Hobt ID, or Allocation Unit ID.

The Objects can be Data Table, View, Stored Proc, Extended Stored Proc, or any other Object that has an Object ID.

Might try OBJECTPROPERTYEX ( ID, PROPERTY ).  See 2008 Books Online for examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found this query where RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID is decoded and used
based on resource_type, and in some cases I noticed that it cannot be decoded.

```sql
/* LOCK MONITOR ON CURRENT schema connections */

Select 
     GETDATE() as Current_Time1,
     es.session_id,
     db_name(sp.dbid) As DatabaseName,
     es.status, 
     substring((Select text
        From sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sp.sql_handle)),1,128) As LastSQLText,
     es.host_name,
     es.login_time,
     es.login_name,
     es.program_name,
     Convert(float, Round((IsNull(es.cpu_time, 0.0) / 1000.00),0)) As  CPU_Time_in_seconds, 
     Convert(float, Round((IsNull(es.lock_timeout, 0.0) / 1000.00),0)) as lock_timeout_in_seconds,
     tl.resource_type As LockType,
     tl.request_mode,
     tl.resource_associated_entity_id,
     CASE 
       WHEN tl.resource_type = 'OBJECT' 
           THEN OBJECT_NAME(tl.resource_associated_entity_id) 
       WHEN tl.resource_type IN ('KEY', 'PAGE', 'RID')      
            THEN       (          SELECT object_name(object_id)         
                                      FROM sys.partitions  ps1
                                               WHERE ps1.hobt_id=tl.resource_associated_entity_id  
                       )
       ELSE 'n.a.' 
     END AS ObjectName,         
     tl.request_status As LockStatus,
     ec.connect_time,
     ec.net_transport,
     ec.client_net_address,
     er.connection_id, 
     Case er.blocking_session_id
       When 0  Then 'Not Blocked'
       When -2 Then 'Orphaned Distributed Transaction'
       When -3 Then 'Deferred Recovery Transaction'
       When -4 Then 'Latch owner not determined'
       Else ''
     End As Blocking_Type, 
     er.wait_type, 
     Convert(float, Round((IsNull(er.wait_time, 0.0) / 
                         1000.00),0)) As Wait_Time_in_seconds,
     er.percent_complete,
     er.estimated_completion_time,
     Convert(float, Round((IsNull(er.total_elapsed_time, 0.0) 
                         / 1000.00),0)) As Total_Elapsed_Time_in_seconds,
     Case er.transaction_isolation_level
       When 0 Then 'Unspecified'
       When 1 Then 'ReadUncomitted'
       When 2 Then 'ReadCommitted'
       When 3 Then 'Repeatable'
       When 4 Then 'Serializable'
       When 5 Then 'Snapshot'
       Else ''
     End transaction_isolation_level          
From            master.sys.dm_exec_sessions    es
     Inner Join master.sys.sysprocesses        sp
        On sp.spid = es.session_id
      Left Join master.sys.dm_exec_connections ec
        On ec.session_id = es.session_id
      Left Join master.sys.dm_exec_requests    er
        On er.session_id = es.session_id
      Left Join master.sys.dm_tran_locks       tl
        On tl.request_session_id = es.session_id
Where  es.session_id <> @@spid
 And es.session_id =  es.session_id
 And sp.dbid = DB_ID() /* CURRENT DB TO MONITOR */
 And tl.resource_type <> 'DATABASE';

raiserror( '- ', 10, 3 ) with nowait;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';

GO 30
```

Answer (score 0):

AJM has stated that he is seeing these unknown object IDs when RESOURCE_TYPE is OBJECT. According to the Books Online the content of the RESOURCE_ASSOCIATED_ENTITY_ID should be an object id (not a Hobt ID or Allocation Unit ID) in this circumstance. The actual wording is "Represents a database object. This can be a data table, view, stored procedure, extended stored procedure, or any object with an object ID".

However, I am able to recreate the problem in my environment (SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition version 9.00.3282.00, SP1). I've tried the OBJECTPROPERTYEX suggestion, but it also returns NULL. Again, this suggests that the mystery objects are not schema-scoped, but unfortunately I also can't work out what they are.